# Using Spring-Data-Neo4j advanced mapping mode in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, aspectj, spring-data-neo4j, sbt-aspectj

I'd like to use the [advanced mapping mode](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#reference%3aaspectj) of spring-data-neo4j in my Scala SBT project ([hosted on github](https://github.com/fdietze/spring-data-neo4j-aspects-sbt-example)):

I can store Nodes in the database with the repository, but I cannot make the aspectj-weaving work.

This is what I have so far:

**build.sbt:**

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
  "spring" at "http://repo.spring.io/milestone",
  "neo4j-releases" at "http://m2.neo4j.org/releases/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j"         % "3.0.0.M1"      % "compile",
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j-aspects" % "3.0.0.M1"      % "compile",
  "javax.persistence"        % "persistence-api"           % "1.0"           % "compile",
  "javax.validation"         % "validation-api"            % "1.0.0.GA"      % "compile",
  "junit"                    % "junit"                     % "4.11"          % "test",
  "com.novocode"             % "junit-interface"           % "0.9"           % "test",
  "org.springframework"      % "spring-test"               % "4.0.0.RELEASE" % "test"
)


Seq(aspectjSettings: _*)

verbose in Aspectj := false

showWeaveInfo in Aspectj := false

inputs in Aspectj <+= compiledClasses

binaries in Aspectj <++= update map { report:UpdateReport =>
  report.matching(
     moduleFilter(organization = "org.springframework.data", name = "spring-data-neo4j-aspects")
  )
}

products in Compile <<= products in Aspectj

products in Runtime <<= products in Compile
```

**project/plugins.sbt:**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-aspectj" % "0.9.4")
```

**Node class and repository:**

```
@NodeEntity
class Node {
  @GraphId
  private var graphId: java.lang.Long = _
}

trait NodeRepository extends GraphRepository[Node]
```

**Test:**

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = Array("classpath*:/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml"))
@RunWith(classOf[SpringJUnit4ClassRunner])
class SDNTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
  @Autowired private var nodeRepository: NodeRepository = null

  @Test
  def persist {
    val node = new Node()
    //nodeRepository.save(node)
    node.persist()
  }

}
```

When I try to run the test, I get these errors:

```
$ sbt test

[info] Weaving 1 input with 1 AspectJ binary to target/scala-2.10/aspectj/classes...
[error] error at sdntest/Node.scala::0 The type sdntest.Node must implement the inherited abstract method org.springframework.data.neo4j.aspects.core.GraphBacked.setPersistentState(Ljava/lang/Object;)
[error]     see also: org/springframework/data/neo4j/aspects/core/GraphBacked.java::0
[error]     see also: org/springframework/data/neo4j/aspects/support/node/Neo4jNodeBacking.aj:66::0
[error] error at sdntest/Node.scala::0 The type sdntest.Node must implement the inherited abstract method org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.ManagedEntity.setPersistentState(Ljava/lang/Object;)
[error]     see also: org/springframework/data/neo4j/mapping/ManagedEntity.java::0
[error]     see also: org/springframework/data/neo4j/aspects/support/node/Neo4jNodeBacking.aj:66::0
[warn] warning at /home/felix/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework.data/spring-data-neo4j-aspects/jars/spring-data-neo4j-aspects-3.0.0.M1.jar!org/springframework/data/neo4j/aspects/support/relationship/Neo4jRelationshipBacking.class:64::0 advice defined in org.springframework.data.neo4j.aspects.support.relationship.Neo4jRelationshipBacking has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[warn] warning at /home/felix/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework.data/spring-data-neo4j-aspects/jars/spring-data-neo4j-aspects-3.0.0.M1.jar!org/springframework/data/neo4j/aspects/support/relationship/Neo4jRelationshipBacking.class:167::0 advice defined in org.springframework.data.neo4j.aspects.support.relationship.Neo4jRelationshipBacking has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
[warn] warning at /home/felix/.ivy2/cache/org.springframework.data/spring-data-neo4j-aspects/jars/spring-data-neo4j-aspects-3.0.0.M1.jar!org/springframework/data/neo4j/aspects/support/relationship/Neo4jRelationshipBacking.class:174::0 advice defined in org.springframework.data.neo4j.aspects.support.relationship.Neo4jRelationshipBacking has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
org.aspectj.bridge.AbortException: AspectJ failed
    at com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj$Ajc$.runAjcMain(SbtAspectj.scala:220)
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I `git clone`d the project, but when `sbt test` I ended up with `sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.neo4j#neo4j-cypher-dsl;2.0.0-M06: not found`. Where did you find it?

Comment: True, the neo4j-resolver was missing. I just pushed the fix.

Answer (score 0):

If you bump the sbt version to 0.13.2 it now works:

project/build.properties ->

```
sbt.version=0.13.2
```

My guess is something about the aspectj plugin doesn't work in older sbt builds.

Comment: I'm getting the same errors as before. Is the test passing for you?

Comment: yes.  You may need to clean out ~/.sbt/boot or ~/.ivy2/.  Not sure what's going on in your system.

Comment: Still not working... I removed ~/.sbt, ~/.ivy2 and made sbt clean and clean-files. Are you using the same code as me? (just pushed it to https://github.com/fdietze/spring-data-neo4j-aspects-sbt-example/tree/sbt132). From my understanding it didn't work earlier, because ajc can not compile Scala itself and spring-data-neo4j does not work by weaving only the class files. So what could have changed?